# Trying to get category id on blog page

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla3.1

I'm trying to get category id of each post with this:

```
$catid = JRequest::getInt('catid');
```

I put this script on blog_item.php

But I get only 0 to all posts

Comment: JRequest is a deprecated method in since 12.1. Use JInput. You can get the request using JFactory::getApplication()->input->getInt("catid");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template is loaded with the context of a `ContentViewCategory`. It allows only one main category, and its id can be obtained by using:

```php
$mainCatid = $this->category->id
```

The current item's immediate parent's id can be obtained by querying the item's `catid` property. There are plenty of other properties available, including category name.

```php
$catid = $this->item->catid
```

Comment: Thanks. I got the parent category (blog). But I need the children category of each post.

Comment: For each post would b from the item not from the request.